# How to use view model together with i18n model?

Tags: sapui5

I've know that how to use view mode as conditional statements：

`title="{= ${viewModel>/mode} === 'edit'? 'Edit': 'Add'}"`

But how to use i18n in this statements?

One way I can think of is use formatter:

```
title="{
    path: 'viewModel>/mode',
    formatter: '.formatter.dialogTitle'
}"
```

Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to replace hardcoded values of "Edit" and "Add" with i18n references.
In this case, you may use the references right in your conditional binding, like so:

```
title="{= ${viewModel>/mode} === 'edit' ? ${i18n>edit} : ${i18n>add} }"
```

Comment: What if I want to provide a third option when mode is "", return "" ?

Comment: It's technically possible to be done with expression binding (more on that here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0), but I would rather use a formatter function instead. Expression binding is a simplified version of a formatter, designed for trivial cases.